# Y axis labels are getting cut in matplotlib, how should I increase boundary from outside

Tags: matplotlib

[image]

Top Y axis label is 'The Shawshank Redemption' but its just showing 'e Shawshank Redemption', remaining part is getting cut. How to I increase boundary outside Y axis??

Comment: Did you try `plt.tight_layout()`?

Comment: Or constrained_layout